# Using Grid and thumbnails to create a photo gallery

Tags: templates, grid, image

I am building a photo gallery. I have a folder called "_small" which has small thumbnail images in to of the photo gallery images. I am using Expression image Grid to build the page. How do I call the the small image since the code already requires a ":"

Here is my code

```
{photos}
    <img src="{photos:image:small}" alt="{photos:image_name}"> 
{/photos}
```

In other areas I called thumbs by using something like this:

```
<img src="{image:small}" alt="{image_name}">
```

But grid requires the field followed by a : to work, which seems like to many :'s to process. Any thoughts.
Thanks for looking!

Comment: is 'image' the name of the field in your channel storing the image?

Comment: Image is the Grid field name where the image file is stored

Comment: I'm confused - does your code sample work or not? The format looks correct - grid_field_name:grid_column_name:image_manipulation_name.  If it doesn't work, are you getting errors?

Comment: It is resolved, quite honestly I am not sure what started working but {photos:image:small} now does. Thanks everyone for your input!

Answer (score 1):

Check out this tutorial from Mike Boying covering this exact subject: [responsive portfolio site using Grid](http://www.train-ee.com/courseware/free-tutorials/comments/implementing-the-work-section-part-3)

His code for the slides looks similar to what you need.